# Are calls to subscribe's consumer argument sequential in Project Reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

With the following code:

```
flux.subscribe(consumer)
```

the calls to `consumer` may take place on different threads, depending on how `flux` was constructed (e.g., with the use of `subscribeOn` or `publishOn`).  Is there a guarantee that, even though calls to `consumer` may take place on different threads, the calls are sequential, i.e., each call completes before the next one starts?

A more specific example below (using Reactor-Kafka):

```
val resultFlux: Flux<Pair<TopicPartition, Long>> = KafkaReceiver
    .create<K, V>(receiverOptions)
    .receive()
    .groupBy { m -> m.receiverOffset().topicPartition() }
    .flatMap { partitionFlux ->
        val parallelRoFlux = partitionFlux
                .publishOn(scheduler)
                .flatMapSequential(::processRecord, parallelism)
        parallelRoFlux.map { ro ->
            acknowledge(ro)
            Pair(ro.topicPartition(), ro.offset())
        }
    }

resultFlux.doOnNext { Thread.sleep(2000); log.info("doOnNext: $it") }
        .subscribe { Thread.sleep(1000); log.info("subscribe: $it") }
```

produces the following output snippet:

```
13:44:26.401 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerSvcFlow - Message_5>>>processed
13:44:28.402 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerExecutable - doOnNext: (demo-topic-0, 15)
13:44:29.402 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerExecutable - subscribe: (demo-topic-0, 15)
13:44:29.435 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerSvcFlow - Message_8>>>processed
13:44:31.435 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerExecutable - doOnNext: (demo-topic-0, 16)
13:44:32.436 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerExecutable - subscribe: (demo-topic-0, 16)
13:44:32.461 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerSvcFlow - Message_9>>>processed
13:44:34.462 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerExecutable - doOnNext: (demo-topic-0, 17)
13:44:35.462 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerExecutable - subscribe: (demo-topic-0, 17)
13:44:35.494 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerSvcFlow - Message_15>>>processed
13:44:37.494 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerExecutable - doOnNext: (demo-topic-0, 18)
13:44:38.495 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerExecutable - subscribe: (demo-topic-0, 18)
13:44:38.497 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerSvcFlow - Message_18>>>processed
13:44:40.498 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerExecutable - doOnNext: (demo-topic-0, 19)
13:44:41.499 [elastic-6] INFO  consumerExecutable - subscribe: (demo-topic-0, 19)
13:44:41.539 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerSvcFlow - Message_19>>>processed
13:44:43.540 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerExecutable - doOnNext: (demo-topic-0, 20)
13:44:44.540 [elastic-8] INFO  consumerExecutable - subscribe: (demo-topic-0, 20)
```

The calls to the `subscribe` consumer argument are sequential but some calls are on thread [elastic-6] and some are on thread [elastic-8].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is such a guarantee, per the Reactive Streams specification.

First, the calls might happen on a different thread *than the one from which you called `subscribe()`*. But all *consumer* calls happen on the same thread.

Second, value consumer in the `subscribe(Consumer<T>)` method is actually considered an `onNext` signal in a `Subscriber`, so the spec enforces that such calls are serialized with respect to one another and to `onComplete` and `onError` signals.

Edit: now that you've added some snippet, the fact that you have 2 threads in there comes from the `publishOn` done inside `flatMap`. Each group of the `groupBy` could therefore pick a different `Worker` of the `Scheduler` (if it has many). The processing done in these inner sequences can therefore be executed in parallel. The **result** however, when merged by `flatMap`, are serialized => the `subscribe(Consumer)` are sequential.

Comment: Thanks, Simon.  My logs confirm the second behaviour above, but not the first one.  Here is a snippet:

Comment: The code and log snippets are too long to paste here, but I'd be happy to email them to you.

Comment: `Flux.just(1, 2, 3).publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe(v -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()), e -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()), () -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()));` all steps print `parallel-1`. The only exception I can think of is with the 4 lambdas variant (subscription consumer, which executes in the subscribeOn thread / caller thread)

Comment: so yeah, to be more precise: onNext, onComplete and onError are guaranteed to be serialized, as are their corresponding consumers in subscribe(...), the three of which run in the same thread. the `Subscription` consumer is not guaranteed to run on the same thread as others, however. But if you use that consumer in `subscribe(...)`, you need to perform a `Subscription#request(n)`, which implies that no `onNext` can happen beforehand.

Comment: I have updated the question, adding Kotlin code and log output snippets there.